# What is the most compact way using LINQ to check whether an IEnumerable<int> is ordered?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I figured out a very LINQy way to do it

```
bool isOrdered = ids.Skip(1).Concat(new List<int>() { int.MaxValue })
       .Zip(ids, (y, x) => y >= x)
       .All(z => z);
```

However, it is not very efficient or compact. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

`Aggregate` is a way to walk sequence and keep track of previous item(s)

```
(new int[]{1,2,3}).Aggregate(
   new { IsSorted = true, Previous = int.MinValue },
   (state, current) => new {
       IsSorted = (state.IsSorted && current > state.Previous), 
       Previous = current})
 .IsSorted
```

Unfortunately with `Aggregate` there is no way to stop early unlike with `.Zip()` solution where you can stop early with `.All` as you have in your sample.

Answer (score 2):

```
    var isOrdered = ids.Zip(ids.Skip(1), (curr, next) => curr <= next).All(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to be a bit more constrained and assume that rather than `IEnumerable<int>` you had an `IList<int>` you could do this, which allows you to quit early:

```
ids.Skip(1).Select( (val,ix) => val >= ids.ElementAt(ix-1) ).All( x => x);
```

It would function for any enumerable but it would be O(n^2) in the case where ids is not an IList.  If you need this to work for any IEnumerable than @AlexeiLevenkov's solution is the best one.